# How do I stop react navigation transitions from rendering a new header?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using a stack navigator and a custom header component in React Navigation v2. How do I stop a new header from animating in with my transition on Android? The app does not behave this way on iOS.

[image: Example Animation]